# Yii2 Gridview сортировка по вычисляемым данным

Tags: сортировка, yii2, gridview

Помогите c вопросом сортировки в Yii2 gridview.
Есть модель User, модель UserSearch.

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function rules() { 
        return [
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['phone'], 'string', 'max' => 25],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 100],    
        ];    
    }  
    /* считает рейтинг по заполненным полям в таблице и возвращает результат */
    public function getRating(){
        ...
    } 
}

class UserSearch extends User {
    public $rating;
    public function rules() 
    { 
        return [ 
            ...
            [['rating'], 'safe'],
        ]; 
    } 
    public function search($params){...}
    }
```

В gridview я добавил аттрибут 'rating'.

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'rating',
    ],
]);
```

Он выводит рейтинг, который считается в методе getRating() модели User. Но когда нажимаю на 'Rating' в заголовке таблицы gridview, то получаю ошибку 'Unknown column 'rating'.

В большинстве статей по сортировке gridview описано, как сделать подобную сортировку по связанным полям. В моем случае связи с другими таблицами нету, нету поля rating в таблице Users. Тут просто происходит подсчет рейтинга по заполненности полей в таблице User и вывод результата.
Как сделать фильтр и сортировку по данной колонке в таблице gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сможете перенести логику вычисления getRating() в sql запрос и соотв-но вернуть его в виде доп. поля, то все заведется. А так средствами грида - имхо только если делать полную выборку в массив, вычислять-добавлять это поле руками и скармливать это все гриду (там есть датапровайдер для массивов), но вариант ес-сно так себе. Вы сами понимаете, что поля такого в бд нет, соотв-но нет его и в датапровайдере, чтобы можно было сортировать/пагинировать вся нужная инфа должна быть доступна в момент выборки из бд.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `public` свойство `$rating` в модель `User` и соответствующий геттер:`getRating`, в нем вычисляйте данные. Из `UserSearch` уберите.

Свойство не обязательно должно существовать в базе данных.

Comment: Может кто-то даст более конкретный ответ на этот вопрос? Несмотря на уверения документации, dataProvider созданный через ActiveDataProvider реально не может этого делать. Это сейчас работает через ArrayDataProvider, что не совсем хорошо. Пожалуйста, знающие, дайте ответ, вопрос частый. Описано тут https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html, но оно не работает!